# How to enable/disable certain snippets for specific projects in Sublime Text?

Tags: sublimetext3, sublimetext

I work on Sublime Text 3 and I've installed many snippets for different PHP frameworks for example Codeigniter and Laravel.

Is there any way I can select which snippets to enable for a project? As in if I work on Laravel, the Codeigniter snippets shouldn't show and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is isn't possible. There is a [feature request for snippet exclusion patterns](https://github.com/SublimeTextIssues/Core/issues/901).

A workaround is to separate the snippets into individual packages, then use [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io) to enable and disable the packages on-the-fly (via the Command Palette <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>).

Create individual packages in the following layout:

```
\
+-Packages
      +- snippets_package_name_a
      |       \-*.sublime-snippet
      +- snippets_package_name_b
      |       \-*.sublime-snippet
      ...
```

Find the Packages directory: `Menu > Preferences > Browse Packages...`.

Open the Command Palette: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>

Type the commands:

- `Package Control: Enable Package`
- `Package Control: Disable Package`

Comment: Actually, this is very easy to do. See my answer.

Comment: How do I 'separate the snippets into individual packages'? I'm unable to find the builtin snippets (the ones that ship with sublime).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is quite simple to do. Assuming you have a [`.sublime-project`](http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/file_management/file_management.html#projects) file defined for your current project, select **`Project → Edit Project`**, and in the `"settings"` dict add `"ignored_packages": []` and in the array add the package(s) you want to ignore. Here's an example:

```js
{
    "folders":
    [
        {
            "follow_symlinks": true,
            "path": "/home/mattdmo/Projects/laravel_project_1"
        }
    ],
    "settings":
    {
        "ignored_packages": [
            "CodeIgniter Snippets",
            "CodeIgniter Utilities"
        ]
    }
}
```

The named packages will only be ignored in this project. For a CodeIgniter project, just add your Laravel-related packages.

Comment: This doesn't work for me (Linux Build 3125). Would it override the User defined "ignored_packages" or add to it?

Comment: I think this won't work because some settings seem to be global only: https://forum.sublimetext.com/search?q=ignored_packages. It makes sense with some settings e.g. would it merge or overwrite the user defined settings, how would multiple projects with differing ignored packages work, etc.

Comment: That's very sad but I must agree with @GerardRoche . 
Unfortunately it doesn't work